# Flutter don't update UI from iOS using setState() method

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, setstate

I am invoking a method from native Swift code by using the platform channel like this:

```
channel.invokeMethod(METHOD_NAME, arguments: STRING_ARGUMENT)
```

in my Flutter class I handle the respective method call by using a callback

```
platform.setMethodCallHandler(_receiveFromHost);
```

The setMethodCallHandler() requires the callback to return a Future and I set state in _receiveFromHost method in Dart.
Problem is that my UI is not updated when Swift invokes the callback. Why?

`call.method` catch method string, state is set, but UI don't update.

[video](https://www.screencast.com/t/4lXaaJBO6I)

This is my code in Swift:

```
let flutterEngine = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).flutterEngine
let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine!, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "flutter_apple_pay", binaryMessenger: flutterViewController.binaryMessenger)
        
channel.invokeMethod("sendDidFinishAdding", arguments: "payment success")
```

And this is my code in Flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text("Native Code from Dart"),
      ),
      body: new MyHomePage(title: ""),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _state = "Waiting results...";

  static const platform = const MethodChannel("flutter_apple_pay");

  _MyHomePageState() {
    platform.setMethodCallHandler(_receiveFromHost);
  }

  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   platform.setMethodCallHandler(_receiveFromHost);
  //   super.initState();
  // }

  Future<dynamic> _receiveFromHost(MethodCall call) async {
    List certificatesBase64Encoded;
    String nonceBase64Encoded;
    String nonceSignatureBase64Encoded;
    String state;

    try {
      print(call.method);

      if (call.method == "sendGenerateRequestWithData") {
        final String data = call.arguments;
        final jData = jsonDecode(data);

        certificatesBase64Encoded = jData['certificatesBase64Encoded'];
        nonceBase64Encoded = jData['nonceBase64Encoded'];
        nonceSignatureBase64Encoded = jData['nonceSignatureBase64Encoded'];

        print(certificatesBase64Encoded);
        print(nonceBase64Encoded);
        print(nonceSignatureBase64Encoded);

        state = "sendGenerateRequestWithData";

        platform.invokeMethod("SendTokenizationData", "TokenizationDataString");
      } else if (call.method == "sendDidFinishAdding") {
        final String result = call.arguments;
        print(result);
        state = result;
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    setState(() {
      _state = state;
    });

    print(_state);
  }

  Future<void> _checkCardState() async {
    String cardState;
    const primaryAccountIdentifiers = ["a", "b"];

    try {
      final String result = await platform.invokeMethod(
          "checkCardState", primaryAccountIdentifiers);

      cardState = result;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      cardState = "Failed to Invoke: '${e.message}'.";
    }
    setState(() {
      _state = cardState;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _startApplePay() async {
    const _cardNetwork = "cn/AMEX";
    const _cardHolderName = "pero peric";
    const _primaryAccountIdentifier = "a";
    const _primaryAccountSuffix = "1234";
    const _localizedDescription = "AMEX";

    Map<String, dynamic> resultMap = Map();
    resultMap['cardNetwork'] = _cardNetwork;
    resultMap['cardHolderName'] = _cardHolderName;
    resultMap['primaryAccountIdentifier'] = _primaryAccountIdentifier;
    resultMap['primaryAccountSuffix'] = _primaryAccountSuffix;
    resultMap['localizedDescription'] = _localizedDescription;

    platform.invokeMethod("startApplePay", resultMap);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Check Card State'),
              onPressed: _checkCardState,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Start Apple Pay'),
              onPressed: _startApplePay,
            ),
            Text(_state),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your `call.method` doesn't pass the any of the `if` statements in `_recieveFromHost`. What is the output of `print(call.method)`?

Comment: @Andrej it pass it, state is set, but the UI is not updated